# Filtering Containable Model Results

Tags: cakephp, search, filter, tags, containable

I am trying with the following line of code to filter all the Posts that have certain (irrelevant) conditions, by the tag "who"

$com= $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'contain' => 'Tag.tag="who"'));

However, instead of the results being only the posts with the tags, I get every single post with empty tag arrays for the ones that don't have the tag "who".

I know my question has come up before, but the solutions posted have not worked with my code.
I have tried adapting the code here to my own:
http://web-development-blog.co.uk/2010/09/14/cakephp-habtm-find-with-conditions-and-containable-behavior/, but I get an SQL error stating "Tag.post_id" not found in on clause.

Please help.

Error message when trying to implement code from selected link:

```
SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`,       `Post`.`modified`, `Tag`.`id`, `Tag`.`tag`, `Tag`.`created`, `Tag`.`modified` FROM `posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `tags` AS `Tag` ON (`Tag`.`post_id` = `Post`.`id`) WHERE `Tag`.`tag` = 'who'    1054: Unknown column 'Tag.post_id' in 'on clause'
```

Which is caused by using this:

```
$this->Post->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Tag')));
$this->Post->contain(array(
  'Tag'
));
$com=$this->Post->find('all', array(
  'conditions'=>array('Tag.tag'=>'who') 
));
```

Comment: post your generated sql and results

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are using bindModel wihtout saying the foreignkey or anything, you SHOULD establish the associations in the model and just use this on-the-fly method when is strictly neccesary.

you need to tell cake which foreignkey of not cake will use the default, in your case it will try Tag.post_id.

Also you should use a has many association or at least i think so. I said this beacause i suppose a post may have multiple tags.

once you do the asociation in the model and delete this line

$this->Post->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('Tag')));

it should work perfectly

OR you can do the association with the correct parameters on the fly read the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly) for this, the example that shows how to put the classname is the one you seek, just add the other attributes

EDIT:

Sorry, read something wrong... the has many association doesn't do a join so you have to use contain to specify the condition or add a condition to the association on the fly, here is how your code should look after adding the conditions with contain

```
$contain = array(
  'Tag' => array(
       'conditions'=> array('Tag.tag'=>'who') 
   )
);
$com=$this->Post->find('all', array(
  'contain'=>$contain 
));
```

REMEMBER contain conditions override the conditions in the associations!! if you want to have extra conditions you must add them on the fly something like:

```
$this->Post->hasMany['Tag']['conditions'] += array('Tag.tag'=>'who');
```

Remember that associations on the fly will work for that instance ONLY.

Also you may do a hasmany alias for different types (remember to define always the classname and foreignkey).

Hope it works this time, if not just comment to see it fix ;)

Comment: I am using a hasmany association. What I think was your recommendation resulted in this error: 'Query: SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified` FROM `posts` AS `Post`   WHERE `Tag`.`tag` = 'who'  1054: Unknown column 'Tag.tag' in 'where clause' '

Comment: @user794486 oh, i saw something wrong XD img going to edit my question with the solution.